# Angular - Prevent event looping?

Tags: angularjs, events, infinite-loop

I need your help as I am still having trouble with events handling.
Here is the concept :

To contextualize, let's say that I have visuals items, that I call "components".
A component is defined by 2 javascript objects. One is containing data (like position x, y, width, height, color, etc...). The other one is the view exploiting a 3rd party library named draw2d.
Draw2d uses it's own x y width height color etc... properties. Which mean that I need to "bind" values to always keep them equals.

For this purpose, I just use events. There are 'on' events in draw2d letting me watch theses modifications. For the angular side, I just use the ng-model directive directly on my data bindings. When a data is updated, I update draw2d view, and when the view is edited, I update my data.
This part is working correctly as this is not hard to handle it.

I then tried to implement multiple selection editing. For that, I store in an array every selected component. When a value from the view or from the data is edited, I trig an event which let every selected component to set the same data to the same value. Again, it's working great.

Where i'm starting to struggle hard, it's when I want to edit the position. I don't want every components to be on top of each other. For that, when I edit multiple x or y attributes, instead of positioning elements, I calculate the offset so that every components move with this offset only. Here is where it's not okay. Of course, when an offset is set, others components updates, also trigging their new value, so I'm stuck in a hell loop.

I would like to know if you know any pattern to handle events so that, when you have 2 view and a model, you can stop an event from propagate.

Here is my propagation snippet :

```
scope.canvas.on('figureEdited', function (canvas, event) {
      if (scope.selectedComponents.length > 1) {
        var key = event.key;
        var value = event.value;
        var originComponent = event.origin;
        for (var i = 0; i < scope.selectedComponents.length; i++) {
          var selectedComponent = scope.selectedComponents[i];
          if (selectedComponent !== originComponent) {
            if (key !== 'x' && key !== 'y') {
              selectedComponent.setData(key, value);
            } else {
              var offset = value - event.oldValue;
              selectedComponent.setData(key, selectedComponent.getData(key) + offset, true);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

the issue is caused by

```
selectedComponent.setData(key, selectedComponent.getData(key) + offset, true);
```

It retriggers a figureEdited event, making every component move again by this offset, infinitely (stopped by 10 digest iterations).

I hope this is clear, sorry for the long text and thanks a lot for your help :)

Alann.

Comment: Did you try to write `event.stopPropagation()`  after `scope.canvas.on('figureEdited', function (canvas, event) { ...` ?

Comment: event is a custom object I emit. It doesn't have a stopPropagation() method :(

Answer (score 0):

If the setData call triggers new events synchronously you can ignore events triggered while in your loop by setting an ignore flag and checking it at the start of the function.

```
var ignoreEvent = false;
scope.canvas.on('figureEdited', function (canvas, event) {
    if (ignoreEvent) return;
    ignoreEvent = true;

    //...

    ignoreEvent = false;
});
```